# Angular recieves Html instead of JSON from Django Server's Response

Tags: django, angular, nginx, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

Scenario:
Running my angular8 code which involves http.get using ng serve
Running django Rest Service, which

```
return Response({"product":["mac","alienware"]})
```

(or)

```
return JsonResponse({"product":["mac","alienware"]})
```

It works fine in the front end.

But when working in my VM,
Using Nginx, where the root points the static files built by ng build
and the /api/ refers to the proxy_pass of the websocket of Gunicorn binded

It returns a html file(The index file) as response when printed
and throws error, Json cannot parse because of "<" at position 0.

The request header has "Content-Type": "application/json;",Accept: "application/json",

What solution can be applied? 
[Edit:Adds nginx conf]

```
 upstream app_server {

    server unix:/data/portal/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name abc.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    root /data/portal/static/angular/dist/portal;
    location /static/ {
         alias /data/portal/static/angular/dist/portal/;
    }
    location / {
     root /data/portal/static/angular/dist/portal;
     index  index.html index.htm;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;


     location /api/ {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://app_server/;
     }
   }
  }
```

When I call the same from one component in angular it works,
But call the same from another component it fails

Comment: Share your Nginx conf?

Comment: I have added them now

Comment: This is a typo.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the description while posting here. Still the rest of the description stands

Comment: Try closing the `location / {` section before the `location /api/ {` section

Comment: That wasn't the solution, since it was working for other API calls from the same backend i.e the ones which uses python requests to call 3rd party services, then does json dumps and loads and returns Response but when I create a dictionary , pass it to the Response object and send , its not working

Comment: Can you inspect the request in you browsers devtools? What's actually being returned and with what status code?

Comment: For the other API calls, (the ones which uses python requests dumps,loads and returns Response) sends -> Content-Type: application/json and response is json,
But where as the ones like Response({}) has Content-Type: text/html and Accept-Ranges: bytes additionally

Comment: The request headers have application/json in both the situtations

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the trailing slash of `server url` in
 `location /api/` block

As your current setup, the request will be forwarded as follow:

1. http://app_server/api/products -> http://app_server/products
2. There's no `products` path so as the `location /` rule, you will get `index.html`

Something like this

```
location /api/ {
  ...
  proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with calling the service from angular, while using the ng serve as well the python run, the trailing slashes while calling using httpclient didnt matter.
It gave a 301 permenantly moved and then called the one with the slash which ultimately gave this kind of confused reponse.

Comment: Have you tried my edit nginx config as my answer? When you run `python` server, there was no problem because the request was served directly.